# Django How to organize models so there is only one owner

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models Company and User:

```py
class Company(models.Model):
    name = CharField("Name", max_length=60)
    owner = OneToOneField(
        "Employee", related_name='owner', on_delete=SET_NULL, null=True)

class BaseUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    join_date = DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    name = CharField("Name", max_length=60)
    email = EmailField(('Email'), unique=True)
    company = ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I need to have only one User as owner. I made it so two models point to each other which doesn't seem right. Is there a way to fix it and still have only one possible owner? I know standard way  would be to add `is_owner = Boolean` to User but it allows other Users to be owners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ForeignKey` from the `Company` to the `BaseUser` is sufficient:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = CharField("Name", max_length=60)
    owner = ForeignKey(
        'Employee',
        related_name='companies'
    )

class BaseUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    objects = CustomUserManager()
    join_date = DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    name = CharField("Name", max_length=60)
    email = EmailField(('Email'), unique=True)
    # no company
```

Here we thus link a `Company` to *one* user. Two `Company`s can have the same `owner`, and it is possible that the `BaseUser` has no, one, or more `Company`s where he is the owner.

You can obtain all the companies for which a `BaseUser` is the owner with:

```
myuser.companies.all()
```

If two companies should always point to two different users, you can make use of the [**`OneToOneField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField).

Comment: What if I want to have more then one user under same company and only one of them is owner of his company?

Comment: @Artem: then you can make a `ManyToManyField` on the company with the employees.